# Open links with React.createRef()

Tags: reactjs

I'm a React newbie, and I'm trying to, using createRef() access different expandable cards. My problem though is that right now every time I click a link all the menus are opening.

Here is my code:

```
class RestaurantEditPage extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

// Refs
 this.facilitiesSection = React.createRef();
 this.descriptionSection = React.createRef();
 this.workingHoursSection = React.createRef();
 }
 handleClick() {
  this.facilitiesSection.current.handleExpandChange(true);
  this.descriptionSection.current.handleExpandChange(true);
  this.workingHoursSection.current.handleExpandChange(true);
}

render() {
 return(
  <RestaurantsCompletionSection
    ...
    clickFunction={this.handleClick}
  />
  <FacilitiesSection
   ...
   ref={this.facilitiesSection}
  />
  <DescriptionSection
   ...
   ref={this.descriptionSection}
  />
)}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to use refs for that. Each section could accept a prop that determines whether it is expanded or not. Which section is expanded is then kept in the state of `RestaurantEditPage`.

Comment: How did it work out?

Answer (score 0):

As Felix pointed out in his comment, using a ref is not really needed here. You could simply do something like this:

```
class RestaurantEditPage extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      restaurantsOpen: false,
      facilitiesOpen: false,
      descriptionOpen: false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
   }
 handleClick(section) {
  if (section === 'restaurant') {
    this.setState({ restaurantOpen: !this.state.restaurantsOpen });
  }
  if (section === 'facilities') {
    this.setState({ facilitiesOpen: !this.state.facilitiesOpen });
  }
  if (section === 'description') {
    this.setState({ descriptionOpen: !this.state.descriptionOpen });
  }
 }

render() {
 return(
  <RestaurantsCompletionSection
    ...
    open=(this.state.restaurantsOpen)
    clickFunction={() => this.handleClick("restaurants")}
  />
  <FacilitiesSection
   ...
   open=(this.state.facilitiesOpen)
   clickFunction={() => this.handleClick("facilities")}
  />
  <DescriptionSection
   ...
   open=(this.state.descriptionOpen)
   clickFunction={() => this.handleClick("description")}
  />
)}
```